# Issue while reading excel workbook from assets folder

Tags: android, excel

Normally i like to keep my files for my app in `assets` and then i read my files from that folder. So, when i tried to read my excel file(which is a 97-2003 work book) from assets folder, it failed(Process - 1). However, when i push the file to `/mnt/sdcard/` using `adb.exe` and then try to read from there, it works(Process - 2).

Code for Process - 1 :

```
File inputWorkbook = new File((assetManager.open("myFile.xls")).toString());
```

Exception Shown :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@40cd4ce0: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Code for Process - 2 :

```
File inputWorkbook = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myFile.xls");
```

1> Can any one tell me, what i am doing wrong ?

2> Also, is there any limitation to file size for the files i keep in assets ? If so, then can i keep it some where else ?

Thanks .

**EDIT :** I have got this one to work as :

```
InputStream dbInputStream = context.getAssets().open("myFile.xls");
```

Still, i will like to know any alternative solutions, if some one has such solutions as well as the answer to my 2nd question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (Read from assets folder):

```
AssetManager assetManager =   m.getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().getAssets();
InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
```

Another way  (Read from /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/file)

```
File file = new File(m.getInstrumentation().getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```